# Does firefox block ajax requests from local files from even being sent out

Tags: javascript, firefox, xmlhttprequest, cross-domain, same-origin-policy

I'm familiar with the Same Origin policy, but what I'm wondering is if firefox actually blocks Ajax POST requests from local files. I've been doing some automated javascript testing, and I've enabled CORS on my server, but I actually don't even see the xhr request making it to firebug, which leads me to believe that firefox is completely blocking it.

When I run the same requests in chrome and allow cross domain requests, it works well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All modern browsers do that : they consider all requests using the `file://` protocol as being cross domain.

Comment: Right but would that prevent the request from even being sent? I've enabled CORS on the server, so I want to allow the cross domain request.

Comment: I'm not sure I get you. Are you serving your files using `file://` (in this case you can't set a CORS header) or not (in this case my answer is irrelevant) ?

Comment: I'm using JSTestDriver to run some tests, which I thought were being served with a null origin (local file), turns out it's not. I have a different issue going on. So your answer is correct, thanks.